# Hive cross join fails on local map join

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, cross-join, google-hadoop

Is there a direct way to address the following error or overall a better way to use Hive to get the join that I need? Output to a stored table isn't a requirement as I can be content with an `INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY` to a csv.

I am trying to perform the following cross join. ipint is a 9GB table, and geoiplite is 270MB.

```
CREATE TABLE iplatlong_sample AS
SELECT ipintegers.networkinteger, geoiplite.latitude, geoiplite.longitude
FROM geoiplite
CROSS JOIN ipintegers
WHERE ipintegers.networkinteger >= geoiplite.network_start_integer AND ipintegers.networkinteger <= geoiplite.network_last_integer;
```

I use CROSS JOIN on ipintegers instead of geoiplite because I have read that the rule is for the smaller table to be on the left, larger on the right.

Map and Reduce stages complete to 100% according to HIVE, but then

> 2015-08-01 04:45:36,947 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative
>   CPU 8767.09 sec
>
> MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 2 hours 26
>   minutes 7 seconds 90 msec
>
> Ended Job = job_201508010407_0001
>
> Stage-8 is selected by condition resolver.
>
> Execution log at: /tmp/myuser/.log
>
> 2015-08-01 04:45:38   Starting to launch local task to process map
>   join; maximum memory = 12221153280
>
> Execution failed with exit status: 3
>
> Obtaining error information
>
> Task failed!
>
> Task ID:   Stage-8
>
> Logs:
>
> /tmp/myuser/hive.log
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
>
> MapReduce Jobs
>   Launched: Job 0: Map: 38  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 8767.09 sec
>   HDFS Read: 9438495086 HDFS Write: 8575548486 SUCCESS

My hive config:

```
SET hive.mapred.local.mem=40960;
SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.intermediate = true;
SET hive.optimize.skewjoin = true;
SET mapred.compress.map.output=true;
SET hive.stats.autogather=false;
```

I have varied `SET hive.auto.convert.join` between **true** and **false** but with the same result.

Here are the errors in the output log from /tmp/myuser/hive.log

```
$ tail -12 -f tmp/mysyer/hive.log

2015-08-01 07:30:46,086 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Execution failed with exit status: 3
2015-08-01 07:30:46,086 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - Obtaining error information
2015-08-01 07:30:46,087 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) -
Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-8

Logs:

2015-08-01 07:30:46,087 ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - /tmp/myuser/hive.log
2015-08-01 07:30:46,087 ERROR mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:execute(268)) - Execution failed with exit status: 3
2015-08-01 07:30:46,094 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
```

I am running the hive client on the Master, a Google Cloud Platform instance of type n1-highmem-8 type (8 CPU, 52GB) and workers are n1-highmem-4 (4CPU 26GB), but I suspect after MAP and REDUCE that a local join (as implied) takes place on the Master. Regardless, in bdutils I configured the JAVAOPTS for the worker nodes (`n1-highmem-4`) to: `n1-highmem-4`

**SOLUTION EDIT:** The solution is to organize the data the range data into a range tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to perform this kind of cross join brute force - just multiply the row numbers, it's a little out of hand. You need some optimizations, which I don't think hive is capable yet.

But is this problem can actually be solved in O(N1+N2) time providing you have your data sorted (which hive can do for you) - you just go through both lists simultaneously, on each step getting an ip integer, seeing if any intervals start on this integer, adding them,  removing those that ended, emitting matching tuples, and so on. Pseudocode:

```
intervals=[]
ipintegers = iterator(ipintegers_sorted_file)
intervals = iterator(intervals_sorted_on_start_file)
for x in ipintegers:
    intervals = [i for i in intervals if i.end >= x]

    while(intervals.current.start<=x):
        intervals.append(intervals.current)
        intervals.next()
    for i in intervals:
        output_match(i, x)
```

Now, if you have an external script/UDF function that knows how to read the smaller table and gets ip integers as input and spits matching tuples as output, you can use hive and `SELECT TRANSFORM` to stream the inputs to it.

Or you can probably just run this algorithm on a local machine with two input files, because this is just O(N), and even 9 gb of data is very doable.

Comment: Indeed, that will be sorta my next approach. I will have hive sort tables by ipinteger and ip range. The upper and lower bounds in the range *should be* unique. So the script will read an ipinteger, check against upper and lower bounds of the range. If false, next interval. If true, emit and start comparison at last checked interval.

Comment: OK I think my implementation of this is O(n*m) still and will take days to complete. How would you make it faster? https://gist.github.com/bbopen/f94e407cef881085599f

Comment: Of course O(n*m) will take forever. Updated my answer with pseudocode.

Comment: The faster I ended up implementing is to structure the range data into a range tree.